# AttributeError when using memcache.gets()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

I am trying to use memcached with Google App Engine. I import the library using

`from google.appengine.api import memcache`

and then call it using

`posts = memcache.gets("posts")`

Then I get the following error:
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gets'`

I have looked through the Google App Engine documentation regarding memcache, but I can't find any examples using memcache.gets(). Memcache.get() seems to be used the way I call gets above.

Answer (score 2):

`gets` is a method of the `memcache` client object, **not** a module-level function of `memcache`.  The module-level functions are quite simple, stateless, and synchronous; using the client object, you can do more advanced stuff, if you have to, as documented at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass .

Specifically, per the docs at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_gets , "You use" `gets` "rather than `get` if you want to avoid conditions in which two or more callers are trying to modify the same key value at the same time, leading to undesired overwrites." since `gets` also gets (and stashes in the client object) the `cas_id` which lets you use the `cas` (compare-and-set) call (you don't have to explicitly handle the `cas_id` yourself).

Since it doesn't seem you're attempting a compare-and-set operation, I would recommend using the simpler module-level function `get`, rather than instantiating a client object and using its instance method `gets`.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually *do* need to compare and set, a very good explanation can be found [here](http://neopythonic.blogspot.pt/2011/08/compare-and-set-in-memcache.html):

> The Client object is required because the gets() operation actually
>   squirrels away some hidden information that is used by the subsequent
>   cas() operation. Because the memcache functions are stateless (meaning
>   they don't alter any global values), these operations are only
>   available as methods on the Client object, not as functions in the
>   memcache module. (Apart from these two, the methods on the Client
>   object are exactly the same as the functions in the module, as you can
>   tell by comparing the documentation.)

The solution would be to use the class:

```
client = memcache.Client()
posts = client.gets("posts")
...
client.cas("posts", "new_value")
```

Although, of course, you would need more than that for cas to be useful.